# Finding new line char c++

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm making a calculator and it returns the result if it finds char print. But if the user input enter nothing happens, so i would like to add to this function (below) that if it finds new line char it would return Token print.

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;          

switch (ch) {
case '\n':               // i made this but it s not working
    return Token(print); // 
case print:
case ',':
case '!':
case '(':
case ')':
case '+':
case '-':
case '*':
case '/':
case '%':
case '=':
    return Token(ch); 
case '.':             
case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':    
{
              cin.putback(ch);
              double val;
              cin >> val;     
              return Token(number, val);
}
default:
    if (isalpha(ch)) {
        string s;
        s += ch;
        while (cin.get(ch) && (isalpha(ch) || isdigit(ch) || ch == '_')) s += ch;
        cin.putback(ch);
        if (s == declkeyz) return Token(zmienna); 
        if (s == declkeyc) return Token(stala); 
        if (s == pierw) return Token(pier);
        if (s == poteg) return Token(pot);
        if (s == kon) return Token(quit);
        return Token(name, s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `print`? You have a case for it...

Comment: It s a const char  = ';'

Comment: looks like you cannot do it this way: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2624/

Comment: See my edit to @Joachim Pileborg's answer for use of `noskipws` and `isspace()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the input operator `>>` by default *skips* whitespace.

Use [`std::noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) input manipulator to change the behavior.

## Edit

Addressing OP's comment about `isspace()` they could do:

```
cin >> noskipws >> ch
if (isspace(ch)) {
    // handle white space case
}
switch(ch)
...
```

Comment: Ok it's working, but there is another problem when user inputs space or other whitespace program crashes.

i've read that i should use isspace with special treatment of '\n' but i have no idea how to implement this.